# Quais diferenças há em utilizar um arquivo .txt e .bat no python?

Tags: python, batch, txt

Estou procurando formas práticas e simples de se salvar informação em um arquivo a parte, que mesmo após o fechamento do programa.py (Em python) a informação não se perca. E nisso ficou um dúvida, quais as vantagens de se usar um arquivo do tipo .txt e do tipo .bat para armazenas e/ou ler informação? Tem alguma diferença?

Comment: Use um formato estruturado, como o json, dessa conseguirá estruturar teus dados, facilitando uma consulta depois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há muita diferença, eu diria.

Especialmente nesse seu contexto de, pelo que entendi, criar um log para seu código python. É isso mesmo?

De qualquer forma, em essência, o arquivo nem precisaria ter extensão, já que é para conter apenas texto não formatado.

Claro que se é um log para algum outro fim, talvez uma extensão mais conhecida tenha mais praticidade, mas, em resumo: tanto faz.

Comment: A ideia é parecida com o log, mas obrigado pela resposta.